# MaxId in linq query

Tags: linq

I am creating range of student entities in a raw but having problem while assigning sequential order id. I am trying to assign next order number, but all students get same order id.

`newClass.Studends.AddRange(
     newStudents.Select(student=> new Student
     {
         name=student.name,
         orderid= student.AssociatedStudents.Max(as=>as.OrderId) + 1
     })
);`

P.S. The code above is not original code, I tried to create similar code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `+ i++` instead of just `+1`. I mean

```
int i=0;

    newClass.Studends.AddRange( newStudents.Select(student=> new Student { name=student.name, orderid= student.AssociatedStudents.Max(as=>as.OrderId) + i++ }) );
```